# Discord.JS bot not replying to commands nor returning a error in console regarding it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been struggling to get my new Discord bot's command handler to work, While it is seeing the command files (as indicated by its log entry on startup stating the amount of commands it has loaded) it either isn't sending the messages, or it isn't even executing them.

Here's my code:

```
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { token, ownerid, statuses, embedColors, prefix } = require('./cfg/config.json');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
const fs = require('fs');
const { config } = require('process');
client.commands = new Collection();
const commands = [];
const cmdfiles = fs.readdirSync('./cmds').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.clear
    console.log(`Ready to go, Found ${cmdfiles.length} commands and ${statuses.length} statuses!`)
    setInterval(() => {
        var status = Math.floor(Math.random() * (statuses.length -1) +1)
        client.user.setActivity(statuses[status]);
}, 20000)
}),
client.on("error", (e) => console.log(error(e)));
client.on("warn", (e) => console.log(warn(e)));
// Command Handler
    for (const file of cmdfiles) {
        const command = require(`./cmds/${file}`);
        commands.push(command.data);
    }
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) {
        embeds: [{
            title: ":x: Oopsie!",
            color: config.embedColors.red,
            description: `Command ${args.[0]} doesn't exist! Run ${config.prefix}help to see the avaliable commands!`,
            footer: app.config.footer + " Something went wrong! :("
        }];
    } else {
        try {
            client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            embeds: [{
                title: ":x: Oopsie!",
                description: "Command execution failed",
                fields: [
                { name: "Error Message", value: `${e.message}` }
                ],
                footer: app.config.footer + " Something went wrong :("
            }];
        }
        message.channel.send
    }});
client.login(token);
```

and the test command is

```
module.exports = {
    name: "test",
    description: "does as it implies, dingusA",
    async execute(client, message, args) {
        message.channel.send("This is a message!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent in order to receive messages in guilds.
Add the following intent in your code

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES ] 
})
```

This applies to other things as well eg. `DIRECT_MESSAGES` for DMs and etc.